# How to use slash commands outside the database?

Tags: postgresql, shell, psql

I tried to use the query outside of the database. That is, without login to data base
I want to get the result. I found the option (-c). Using that option we can execute the query from outside the data base:

```
test:~$ psql  -U sat -c "select * from test.details";
```

It gives the output. I want to use that query for a crontab entry. So I have tried to store the output in a file:

```
 test:~$ psql  -U sat -c "select * from test.details \g sat";
```

Produced an error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
> LINE 1: select * from test.details \g sat
> ```

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is not a slash, but a backslash .**
Backslash is an escape character in PostgreSQL string literals, therefore you have to double it to get a single backslash into the actual data.
If you want to store the result of a query into a file from the command line you have to use the `-o` command line option,so your query will become :

```
psql  -o filename -U sathishkumar -c "select * from hospital_management.patient_details";
```

Answer (score 3):

There is **no such thing** as a "query outside of the data base" or "without login to data base".

You are trying to mix meta-commands of the **psql** client with SQL commands, which is strictly impossible. The backslash meta commands are interpreted by the psql client, SQL queries are interpreted by the database server.

Most meta-commands in psql are actually translated into (a series of) SQL queries to the database server. You can make psql print the commands it sends to the database engine if you start it up with the command option `-E` in interactive mode. Try:

```
psql -E mydb
```

And then execute any backslash command and observe the output. For the rest of your question @aleroot has already given good advice.